# simple lightbox

Tags: javascript

i need a simple lightbox which not only work for images but also for other link i.e there is a word in a paragraph when i clicked on the word a lightbox apear to me

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: Nobody likes Colorbox? Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 10 of the best. Pick one that suits you:

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts

Sounds like you want one that can handle inlineHTML as well as images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my lightbox: http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/

Works only for images atm. But basically you can use any element to trigger the lightbox.

Cheers